# How to use ReadConsoleOutput func with redirected console?

Tags: c++, winapi, console, handle

I have programm that executes command by creating a new process in new console window. So after writing command in console by WriteFile func i get HANDLE of this window and try to read its output. Particularly I need to get the output of FarManager window that appears in new console but ReadConsoleOutput throws an error (6) that tells about "wrong handle". What ideas could u offer?

Here is a function that gets new console handle.

```
HWND RemoteConsole::GetLastWindowsFromProcessID() {
    HWND vhWnds = 0;
    // find all hWnds (vhWnds) associated with a process id (dwProcessID)
    HWND hCurWnd = NULL;
    do
    {
        hCurWnd = FindWindowEx(NULL, hCurWnd, NULL, NULL);
        DWORD dwProcID = 0;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hCurWnd, &dwProcID);
        if (dwProcID == pi.dwProcessId)
        {
            vhWnds = hCurWnd;  // add the found hCurWnd
        }
    } while (hCurWnd != NULL);

    return vhWnds;
}
```

```
void RemoteConsole::readScreen(void)
{
    
    HANDLE hStdout, hNewScreenBuffer;
    SMALL_RECT srctReadRect;
    SMALL_RECT srctWriteRect;
    CHAR_INFO chiBuffer[160]; // [2][80];
    COORD coordBufSize;
    COORD coordBufCoord;
    BOOL fSuccess;

    // Get a handle to the STDOUT screen buffer to copy from and
    // create a new screen buffer to copy to.

    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    HWND h = GetLastWindowsFromProcessID();
    hNewScreenBuffer = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
        GENERIC_READ |           // read/write access
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ |
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE,        // shared
        NULL,                    // default security attributes
        CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, // must be TEXTMODE
        NULL);                   // reserved; must be NULL
    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ||
        hNewScreenBuffer == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("CreateConsoleScreenBuffer failed - (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Make the new screen buffer the active screen buffer.

    if (!SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hNewScreenBuffer))
    {
        printf("SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer failed - (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Set the source rectangle.

    srctReadRect.Top = 0;    // top left: row 0, col 0
    srctReadRect.Left = 0;
    srctReadRect.Bottom = 1; // bot. right: row 1, col 79
    srctReadRect.Right = 79;

    // The temporary buffer size is 2 rows x 80 columns.

    coordBufSize.Y = 2;
    coordBufSize.X = 80;

    // The top left destination cell of the temporary buffer is
    // row 0, col 0.

    coordBufCoord.X = 0;
    coordBufCoord.Y = 0;

    // Copy the block from the screen buffer to the temp. buffer.

    fSuccess = ReadConsoleOutput(
        h,        // screen buffer to read from
        chiBuffer,      // buffer to copy into
        coordBufSize,   // col-row size of chiBuffer
        coordBufCoord,  // top left dest. cell in chiBuffer
        &srctReadRect); // screen buffer source rectangle

    if (!fSuccess)
    {
        printf("ReadConsoleOutput failed - (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Set the destination rectangle.

    // Copy from the temporary buffer to the new screen buffer.

    
    // Restore the original active screen buffer.

    if (!SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(h))
    {
        printf("SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer failed - (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    /*
        std::string out;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < coordBufSize.Y * coordBufSize.X; i++)
    {
        out += chiBuffer[i].Char.AsciiChar;
    }

    std::cout << out;
    */

}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know how you get the value of `pi.dwProcessId` in the code? Could you show how? Have you considered using [GetStdHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle)

Comment: I created cmd process by CreateProcess and use anonymous pipe to write command and read the output, and I get positive result when executing normal commands(dir, ipconfig) using WriteFile and ReadFile on oposite ends of pipe but in case with farManager it stoppes reading so I decided to try to read it with ReadConsoleOutput but it accepts only handles with GENERIC READ flag and GetStdHandle doesn't suit in that case because I need to use handle from a new console window.